# System::IntPtr to int* in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, interop, c++-cli

I am trying to call an existing C++ library from a C# application using the C++/CLI interop layer. I have a C++ function that looks something like this:

```
void doSomething(int* foo, int size);
```

And a C# object that holds two fields, an IntPtr start, and an int size. I wrote a managed C++ class that looks like this:

```
public ref class Wrapper {
public:
    void run(System::IntPtr itn, int size);
};
```

And now I want to call doSomething in Wrapper::run, and have doSomething have access to the same block of data that the C# object points to. Is what I'm trying to do possible without a copy, and if so, how?

Comment: Surely you meant to write that as `void run(int% itn, int size)`?  If not then memory needs to be pinned by somebody.  Do **not** ignore that requirement, best to do it in C++/CLI with pin_ptr<> so the C# code can simply use int[].

Comment: Sorry, I am new to CLI and C#, I am mostly familiar with C++ and C. What does pinning memory do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call *doSomething* from *Wrapper::run*, try casting the return of [System::IntPtr::ToPointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.topointer), like so:

```
doSomething(reinterpret_cast<int*>(itn.ToPointer()), size);
```